# How do I pass a pointer to a class member function as a callback?

Tags: c++

I have a class member function defined thus:

```
   void A::fn(char * szInput) {
      ///
   }
```

I have an instance of this class:

```
A myInstance();
```

I wish to pass a pointer to myInstance.fn into another class which has a parameter defined thus:

```
    B::B(const char* _szParm1, 
       uint8_t _iParm2, 
       void (* _callback)(char *) {

    }
```

The definition of my callback function matches the definition of the constructor parameter required.

When I am passing the callback function I am passing it thus:

```
    B myClass("abc",1,myInstance.fn);
```

which (In theory) should pass a pointer to myInstance.fn, yet I get an error upon compilation: "invalid use of non-static member function"

This shouldn't be that hard surely?

EDIT:

I'm seeing references to having to declare my callback thus:

```
    B::B(const char* _szParm1, 
       uint8_t _iParm2, 
       void (A::* _callback)(char *) {

    }
```

however I want to avoid this as it limits this particular constructor style to one type of class and I'd rather keep it generic as this is a general pattern for use with a larger set of classes - both member functions and non-member functions.

Comment: Besides callback as `std::function` or `template`, I would use `std::string_view` as a `Parm1` type, or if you do not use C++17 `std::string`. I rely hate `C` style coded classes (`C++` code).

Comment: I think the `void (A::* _callback)(char *)` is probably **not** what you want. In order to call `_callback` in this case, you would need both an instance of `A` and a `char *`. Pointers to member functions are taken from _classes_, not objects, they do not have any instance associated with them. It can be thought as `void func(A* this, char*)` (although not exactly if the pointed member function is virtual).

Comment: @Ivella Yes, this is exactly the problem with going down that route. I am currently investigating std::function however my environment (AVR / embedded) doesn't support this natively so I am looking for other implementations of std::function.

Answer (score 2):

> I'd rather keep it generic as this is a general pattern for use with a larger set of classes - both member functions and non-member functions.

Member function pointers are different with non-member function pointers, they always require an instance to be called on.

You can use `std::function` instead. Then for member functions you can pass a lambda capturing an instance of `A`. (For non-member functions you can pass them to `std::function` directly.)

```
B::B(const char* _szParm1, 
   uint8_t _iParm2, 
   std::function<void (char *)> _callback) {
}
```

then

```
A myInstance;
B myClass("abc",1,[&myInstance](char* szInput) { myInstance.fn(szInput); });
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to limit the type of the function, I see two options: either a template or `std::function`.

The template solution looks like this:

```
template<class F>
B::B(const char* _szParm1, uint8_t _iParm2, F&& _callback);
```

The `std::function` solution looks like this:

```
B::B(const char* _szParm1, uint8_t _iParm2, std::function<void(char*)> _callback);
```

Each has its own advantages and drawbacks. The template solution is less flexible, because you don't know the type of the callback outside of the template function itself, so you can't, for instance, declare a member variable in class B of type `F` to store the callback. If you want to store the callback and don't want to make B itself a template, then your best option is to use `std::function`, which has a small runtime penalty.